# The absolute uri: http://www.slf4j.org/taglib/tld cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, slf4j, taglib

I am working in JSP and Servlets, I was trying to use SL4J's TAGLIB instead of using its jar.
But I am getting this error continuously. I am using Pivotal TC Server 2.9.5 for my environment with Tomcat 7 runtime and JDK 1.7 with Spring tool suit 3.

I was using Tomcat 8 runtime before, but somehow I dont know why this error disappeared when I switched from Tomcat 8 to 7. But suddenly I am getting the same error again. I've added SL4J's taglib jar to class path.

This is my **jsp page**

```
<%@ page errorPage="MyErrorPage.jsp"
         info="This JSP Page Written By Usman"
         import="org.slf4j.Logger, org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, java.util.Date, java.text.DateFormat, java.text.SimpleDateFormat"
         session="true"
        %>

<%@ taglib prefix="log" uri="http://www.slf4j.org/taglib/tld" %>        
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="exampleTLD"%>

<html>
    <title>JSP Learning</title>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        <p>Yes finally its working</p>

        <log:warn exception="Some"> -> This is warning </log:warn>
        <ex:Hello message="This is custom tag msg"> >> This is Tag Body <br /></ex:Hello>

        <%--  Logback in jSP --%>
        <%! Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("index.jsp"); %>
        <% log.info("Hello Logging!"); %>

        <% out.println(page + " ^^ this is working" + request.getRemoteAddr() + "<hr />"); %>

        <%--  Getting data from session --%>
        <%
            Date date = new Date(session.getCreationTime());
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH : mm : ss - SSS");
            String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date);

            out.println( dateFormatted + "<hr />");
            out.println(session.getAttributeNames() + "<hr />");
            out.println(session.getLastAccessedTime());
        %>  
    </body>
</html>
```

This is **POM.xml** file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>web Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>web</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is my directory structure

[image]

and this is my build path
[image]

These are my libraries

[image]

But I am getting it in my suggestions. and If I am getting it in suggestion, then why server cant get the absolute URI.

[image]

This is what error I am getting

[image]

Error is in this line

```
<%@ taglib prefix="log" uri="http://www.slf4j.org/taglib/tld" %>
```

Comment: Do you have  `slf4j-api.jar` in your build-path?

Comment: I am using Maven, and its there. Its working fine when I use it as Library.

But when I do it through TAGLIB

It can not find laglib on this path. I followed this
http://www.slf4j.org/taglib/

It was working once, but suddenly it stoped. I just changed my server version. (Tomcat 7 to 8)

Comment: Is this jar in your `WEB-INF/lib` , if not try to add it  .

Comment: added edits with screenshots.

Comment: Please show the Librairies in build-path screen shot and not source

Comment: Try to add the  tomcat server librairies to the build- path : Add library ->Server Runtime-> Apache tomcat 7

Comment: I am using VMWare's TC Server. Which is actually an extention of Tomcat. All those libraries are added.